# how can I make this form display green until all boxes selected?

Tags: jquery

I have a small form, where if the user clicks yes for all questions, then a message appears saying you are qualified.

So in the jQuery code, if the checked values for yes is equal to 4 then the green You are qualified message is displayed. However if the checked values are not equal to 4 then the red error appears saying you are not qualified (even when only two yes values are clicked).

Is there any way that I can change this so that it shows the green qualified message until all  4 radio buttons are checked?

I also have a jsfiddle please see: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/xxfairydragonxx/uhbtmdrd/1/)

```js
$("input").on("click", function() {
  if ($('input[value=yes1]:checked, input[value=yes2]:checked, input[value=yes3]:checked, input[value=yes4]:checked').length === 4) {

    $("#correct").show();
    $("#incorrect").hide();
  } else {
    $("#correct").hide();
    $("#incorrect").show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left question">Do you own a car?</div>
<div class="right answer">
  <div class="leftradio">
    <label>Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" id="yes1" value="yes1" name="iCheck1">
    </input>
  </div>
  <div class="rightradio">
    <label>No</label>
    <input type="radio" id="no1" name="iCheck1"></input>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <div class="left question">Has someone lived with you for at least 6months within the last 4 years?</div>
  <div class="right answer">
    <div class="leftradio">
      <label>Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" id="yes2" value="yes2" name="iCheck2"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="rightradio">
      <label>No</label>
      <input type="radio" id="no2" name="iCheck2"></input>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="left question">Do you have home insurance?</div>
    <div class="right answer">
      <div class="leftradio">
        <label>Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" id="yes3" value="yes3" name="iCheck3">
        </input>
      </div>
      <div class="rightradio">
        <label>No</label>
        <input type="radio" id="no3" name="iCheck3">
        </input>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="left question">Do you spend more than around £400 per month on bills?</div>
    <div class="right answer">
      <div class="leftradio">
        <label>Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" id="yes4" value="yes4" name="iCheck4">
        </input>
      </div>
      <div class="rightradio">
        <label>No</label>
        <input type="radio" id="no4" name="iCheck4">
        </input>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div id="correct">
    <div class="boxtext">
      YOU QUALIFY!</div>
  </div>
  <div id="incorrect">
    <div class="boxtext"><span style="font-weight:bold">X</span>SORRY BUT YOU DON'T QUALIFY!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add classes to the parent, first once there is an answer, and if its invalid(no). Then check if there are four answers and no invalids stay green, else go red.

```js
$("#correct").show();
$("#incorrect").hide();
$( "input" ).on( "click", function() {
    var par=$(this).parent().parent();
    if($(this).attr('id').indexOf('no')>=0 && !par.hasClass('inValid')){
        par.toggleClass('inValid');
    }else if($(this).attr('id').indexOf('yes')>=0 && par.hasClass('inValid')){
        par.toggleClass('inValid');
             }
    if(!par.hasClass('done'))
        par.toggleClass('done');
    if($('.done').length==4&&$('.inValid').length>0){
        $("#correct").hide();
  $("#incorrect").show();
    }else{
        $("#correct").show();
  $("#incorrect").hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left question">Do you own a car?</div>
   <div class="right answer">
    <div class="leftradio">
     <label>Yes</label>
     <input type="radio" id="yes1" value="yes1" name="iCheck1">
     </input>
    </div>
    <div class="rightradio">
     <label>No</label>
     <input type="radio" id="no1" name="iCheck1">
     </input>
    </div>
   </div>
  <div class="right">
  <div class="left question">Has someone lived with you for at least 6months within the last 4 years?</div>
   <div class="right answer">
    <div class="leftradio">
     <label>Yes</label>
     <input type="radio" id="yes2" value="yes2" name="iCheck2">
     </input>
    </div>
    <div class="rightradio">
     <label>No</label>
     <input type="radio" id="no2" name="iCheck2">
     </input>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> 
 <div class="row">
  <div class="left">
 <div class="left question">Do you have home insurance?</div>
   <div class="right answer">
    <div class="leftradio">
     <label>Yes</label>
     <input type="radio" id="yes3" value="yes3" name="iCheck3">
     </input>
    </div>
    <div class="rightradio">
     <label>No</label>
     <input type="radio" id="no3" name="iCheck3">
     </input>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
  <div class="left question">Do you spend more than around £400 per month on bills?</div>
   <div class="right answer">
    <div class="leftradio">
     <label>Yes</label>
     <input type="radio" id="yes4" value="yes4" name="iCheck4">
     </input>
    </div>
    <div class="rightradio">
     <label>No</label>
     <input type="radio" id="no4" name="iCheck4">
     </input>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> 
    </div>
 
   <div class="row">
  <div id="correct">
   <div class="boxtext">
   YOU QUALIFY!</div>
  </div>
  <div id="incorrect"><div class="boxtext"><span style="font-weight:bold">X</span>   SORRY BUT YOU DON'T QUALIFY!</div></div>
 </div>
```

The code snippet doesn't have the colors but jsfiddle does [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1g8kzyq5/)

Comment: hello, thank you i just updated with a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xxfairydragonxx/uhbtmdrd/1/  there are styling rules applied many thanks

Comment: give me a min to redo mine

Comment: Thank you for this it has helped me loads!